# A simple question: can a linear transformation have the same matrix in different bases?

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi: can a linear transformation have the same matrix in different bases? I have spent a whole evening trying to figure out whether this can be to no use. What is certain is that given a base, I can define a linear ttransformation by giving it's values over a base. That is, there exists a function theta from the set of all ordered bases of V to the set of all linear transformations. Does this function have an inverse?

Comment: Cheap example: the linear operator which sends everything to zero has the same matrix for each choice of basis.

Comment: so does the mapping that sends every vector to itself

Comment: "That is, there exists a function theta from the set of all ordered bases of V to the set of all linear transformations."  What you are describing is not function from the set of ordered bases to the set of linear transformations.  A function must have exactly one output for each input.

Answer (score 4):

Saying that a linear operator $f$ has the same matrix $A$ in 2 different bases $B$ and $B'$ means that, if $P$ is the matrix of the coordinates of the vectors of $B'$ relatively to $B$,
$$A=PAP^{-1}$$
Hence
$$AP=PA$$
So it may be possible that a same matrix represent $f$ in two different bases.

Comment: Thanks Paf. Now suppose this is (V,f), the set of all alternate forms over V x V. Then to f there corresponds a sympletic basis, and the values of f are determined by that base, that is, the matrix of f over the base consists of 2 x 2 square blocks with zeroes in the main d iagonal and +/-1 on the other. Can f have the same matrix in another basis. @D_S: if you assign values to each element of a basis you get a linear trasformation, for the value at each element of the domain will be a linear combination of the values at the elements of the base. Am I wrong? Hence, you get a function from the

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly less trivial example (than the zero and identity transformations), which is easily generalized.

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear transformation given by $T(a,b)=(a+3b,2a+4b)$ and let $\beta$ be the standard ordered basis and $\gamma$ be the ordered basis $\gamma=\{(1,2), (3,4)\}$. Then $$[T]_\beta=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3\\
2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
=[T]_\gamma$$